# Change a PHP background colour to a CSS call

Tags: php, css, colors, background

I am no coder but am trying to take anything CSS related out of a php file but require a little help.

How can I re write the below code to get the bgcolor from an external CSS instead of the php doing the job

I just want the bellow rewriting to include the CSS class instead of the code actualy making the color.

Hope you understand what I am saying

first bit of code

```
$bgcolour = ($k % 2) ? 'bgcolor="#FFFEEE"' : '';
```

Second bit of code

```
'ROWCOLOUR' => ($row['highlighted'] == 'y') ? 'bgcolor="#fea100"' : $bgcolour,
```

Comment: use `:even` or `:odd` pseudos, if you attach output markup you have i could provide you complete solution

Comment: @Ben I have no idea the $k has me baffled to I am presuming its a key saying count 2 lines then alternate the color

Comment: @ Evgeniy the only output in the theme for that bit of code is as follows. note that the templating engine used is based around the PhpBB templating engine <tr align="center" {items.ROWCOLOUR}>

Comment: what do you mean by "external"?

Comment: @Soundz exactly what a CSS file is external I.E not an inline style

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css" /> ?

Comment: you can place in your css selector like following : .striped-table tr:even { background-color: #fffeee; } .striped-table tr { background-color: #fea100 }. You just need to find root table and add to this class="striped-table"

Comment: working examples - http://jsfiddle.net/448ds5kw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.fffeee {
  background-color: #FFFEEE;
}

.fea100 {
  background-color: #FEA100;
}
```

PHP:

```
$cssClass = ($k % 2 == 0 && $row['highlighted'] != 'y') ? 'fffeee' : 'fea100';

'ROWCOLOUR' => 'class="' . $cssClass . '"',
```

Comment: Thanks that was the easiest answer for me to understand but is that not still the php creating the color

Comment: This is NOT THE ANSWER please remove it as the answer

Comment: I just had another look and get what it is doing now. I will give this a go. Please dont mark as the answer YET

Comment: @user3604052: You're the owner of the question, it's up to you whether or not you want to mark this as the answer, in your own time.

Comment: Thank you this is just what I needed It works perfect. BIG THUMBS UP

Comment: Thanks for this I am going to ask a new question for you as you seem to be give the best answer I have found. I will come back here and edit this with a link to the new question. THANKS BUD

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .mouseoverbg{
        background-color : #eeefff;
    }
    .oddrowbg{
            background-color : #fffeee;
    }
    .evenrowbg{
            background-color : #fea100;
    }
</style>
<table>
<?php
$ni = 5;
for($i=0 ; $i<$ni; $i++)
{
    $bgcolor = ($i%2)?"evenrowbg" : "oddrowbg";
    ?>
    <tr onmouseover="this.className='mouseoverbg'"  onmouseout="this.className='<?php echo $bgcolor?>'" class="<?php echo $bgcolor?>">
    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}?>
</table>
```

Try this code it may help you.

Comment: try change color for first class, as i checked it was working for mouse over.