# Change a PHP coded background colour to CSS

Tags: php, css, class

This is a follow up to my previous question **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503232/change-a-php-background-colour-to-a-css-call?noredirect=1#comment39811926_25503232)**.

The next bit of code I am looking for help on is below.

I wish to take the #FFFFFF from the below code and make this look to an external CSS file for the COLOUR the code in the PHP at the moment is as below

```
'COLOUR' => (empty($row['cat_colour'])) ? '#FFFFFF' : $row['cat_colour'],
```

The CSS I wish to use is

```
/* index page category background colour */
.cat_colour {
background-color: #c0c0c0c0;
}
```

How do I convert

```
'COLOUR' => (empty($row['cat_colour'])) ? '#FFFFFF' : $row['cat_colour'],
```

to use the

```
    /* index page category background colour */
.cat_colour {
background-color: #c0c0c0c0;
}
```

from my external style sheet

The code

```
'COLOUR' => (empty($row['cat_colour'])) ? '#FFFFFF' : $row['cat_colour'],
```

Is the only bit of code that makes the text background a white colour no other code is involved in this.

The full PHP code is below.

```
// prepare categories list for templates/template
// Prepare categories sorting
if ($system->SETTINGS['catsorting'] == 'alpha')
{
$catsorting = ' ORDER BY cat_name ASC';
}
else
{
$catsorting = ' ORDER BY sub_counter DESC';
}

$query = "SELECT cat_id FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories WHERE parent_id = -1";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);

$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "categories
WHERE parent_id = " . mysql_result($res, 0) . "
" . $catsorting . "
LIMIT " . $system->SETTINGS['catstoshow'];
$res = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$template->assign_block_vars('cat_list', array(
'CATAUCNUM' => ($row['sub_counter'] != 0) ? '(' . $row['sub_counter'] . ')' : '',
'ID' => $row['cat_id'],
'IMAGE' => (!empty($row['cat_image'])) ? '<img src="' . $row['cat_image'] . '" border=0>' : '',
'COLOUR' => (empty($row['cat_colour'])) ? '#FFFFFF' : $row['cat_colour'],
'NAME' => $category_names[$row['cat_id']]
));
}
```

The output as it is currently in the template is as below

```
<!-- BEGIN cat_list -->
<li>
<span style="{cat_list.COLOUR}">
<a href="browse.php?id={cat_list.ID}">{cat_list.IMAGE}{cat_list.NAME}</a>     {cat_list.CATAUCNUM}
</span>
</li>
<!-- END cat_list -->
```

Any help is most appreciated, but please explain it in a manner that a complete novice of PHP can understand.

I have tried recoding the original code that I got in my last thread to use in this code and have even tried making my own by dissecting bits of the original code and the previous threads' code but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Where is `$row['cat_colour']` stored?

Comment: @Gudip It's not I think thats why it is an EMPTY $row I checked every file for $row['cat_colour'] and the only mention of it is in the file I am working with index.php, CODE AS POSTED ABOVE

Comment: Change `#FFFFFF` in your code to `#c0c0c0c0`

Comment: @Gudip I want it to look to the CSS for the colour, changing #FFFFFF to #C0C0C0 in the index.php in the above code is not looking to the external CSS style.css but is just changing the PHP to display grey instead of white. I want this to be editable from the CSS not directly in the PHP

Comment: Why are you using php to do this? Just link the css style sheet in the html and give it a class. This is not how styles should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a CSS file and reference it in the head of your index.php, like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH/TO/YOUR/CSSFILE.css" />`

Delete the COLOUR line in your PHP. You won't need it anymore.

Then, give whatever HTML element that needs to change colour the class of "cat_colour" (like this: `<li class="cat_colour"> ... </li>`, if you want the `li` to change colour), and paste your css code into your css file.

Comment: This is about changing PHP code not about how you make a CSS file then link to it I already know all that. Thanks for the answer but please read a post properly before making answers to them

Comment: You should ask your question properly. You have clearly no idea what is behind that template/CMS.